# Displaying a Integer with thousand seperator

Tags: c#, int, string.format

i want to display a integer value with a thousand seperator. i found following ways:

```
int i = 0101010101;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("N0")); // 101.010.101
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("#,#"));// 101.010.101
```

what's the difference / advantage of each?

Comment: They creates different results for different inputs. For your example, result can be different with a different culture (beside your `CurrentCulture`) for example. Have you ever read their documentations first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one difference. If you test it with `i = 0`, then the `"N0"` format string outputs `0`, and the `"#,#"` format string outputs nothing at all. As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierD) states:

> Note that this specifier never displays a zero that is not a significant digit, even if zero is the only digit in the string. It will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the number that is being displayed.